# Gerund vs noun-- which to use in title

Tags: word-choice, nouns, gerunds, titles

This issue of **gerunds vs noun** always puzzled me and in this particular case made me wonder. I actually am translating my thesis title into English and am not sure as to use gerund or noun. So which one do you think is correct:

1. ***development*** and ***presentation*** of the integrated model
2. ***developing*** and ***presenting*** the integrated model

*I* have actually developed the model, if that makes any difference.

It would mean alot to me to make it clear this old question. Namaste ;)

Comment: This may be closed as 'primarily opinion based' as neither phrase is incorrect. Which is more idiomatic probably depends on the context, which it would be better to provide. 'Development and presentation of the integrated model' sounds rather lacking in detail for a complete thesis title.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. The complete title goes like ***Developing and presenting the integrated model of GSCM and GHRM (Superpipe int. case study)***

Comment: The _ing_-form variant is certainly at least a little less formal than the nounal variant. It's perhaps not the one to choose for an academic paper. But this is a style choice; doesn't your institution have a style guide addressing the issue? Have you looked at a spread of other thesis titles?  If these don't help, you could run it past your tutor (tell them you've tried 3 other routes).

Comment: Simply adding -ing to a word does not make it a gerund. A gerund is a noun, as in "Reading helps you learn English." You can see that "reading" is a noun by replacing it with a pronoun: "Reading? It helps you learn English." In "Developing and presenting the integrated model of GSCM and GHRM," the -ing words are not gerunds--they are present participles. As to which of your choices is correct, it's a matter of preference, as the above comment indicates. Both work fine.

Answer (score -1):

I'll take a guess you say it's a CV you are putting together, am I right?

Context is everything, as is who is writing (you, in this case) and to whom.

I would use a gerund phrase (instead of a noun phrase), as it is you and since it emphasizes the activity (action) rather than the 'topic'.